# How can I set the orientation for a 3D Matplotlib Figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to plot a 3D surface, with the following code:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)
ax.set_aspect('equal') # not relevent to the problem
plt.show()
```

Now, this outputs a figure, as one would expect, but the problem is that the axes are a little unconventional.[image]

I would like to output the figure such that the x, y (not necessarily z) axes zeros line up, or essentially, like the following (which can be obtained by just panning the figure manually):[image]

Is there a `matplotlib.pyplot` command I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

Include the line `ax.view_init(45,45)` before calling `plt.show()`.

#### Explanation

`ax.view_init(...)` is a command which sets the initial perspective of a subplot when `plt.show()` is called. It takes in four parameters `elev=None, azim=None, roll=None, vertical_axis='z'`. All of them have a default, so for your purpose, you will only need to include the two float values for the elevation and azimuth.

Link to documentation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.view_init.html

Comment: This is not quite what I wanted. I wanted `ax.view_init(azim = 225)`. However, because that was the key I was missing, I'm still accepting it as an answer. Thanks!